# How to copy dll file from visual studio solution to specific location on drive

Tags: visual-studio

I'm making a mod for Red Dead Redemption 2 and I'm trying to use xcopy to copy the dll file from the visual studio folder to my red dead redemption 2 script folder without having to manually move it every time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to C#. Though that may be what you wrote the mod in, that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Okay. [Microsoft has documentation for xcopy on the web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy). What's your question?

Comment: You might also look into [build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019) if you want this to run every time you successfully build your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

A general tool for copying files around - and other things that are not directly supported by Visual Studio - is gulp, which can be integrated into your Visual Studio build.

See: https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add a post-build step by adding the following element to your `.csproj` file:

`<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(TargetName).dll C:\DestinationDirectory\$(TargetName).dll /F /Y" />
</Target>`